# How to overcome CORS redirect issue while performing post operation via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cors

I'm able to get signed in to the roundcube instance (hosted at another server) via form submission with post method type from external login form.

I'm getting this error (While signing via ajax):

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://192.168.0.7/mail/. The request was redirected to 'https://192.168.0.7/mail/?_task=mail&_token=36e97d50951472c4c65de562a0109e94', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://192.168.0.7/mail/',
    data: {
        _user: 'myusername', _pass:'mypassword', _autologin: 1, _action: 'login',_task: 'login'
    },
    success: function( data ){
        $('#result').html(data);
    },
    crossDomain: true,
});
```

I have overcome all CORS related issue except this one. I know it is default browsers behavior to disallow redirection at cross-sites. Please Suggest, If there is a way to get this problem solved or should i move on to look for another way?

Thanks

Comment: this link might help u. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539403/chrome-cancels-cors-xhr-upon-http-302-redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
```

You should add all methods in the header that you need access to.

Comment: I tried with this option also, I google and i found we need to make first OPTIONS request alone than POST to overcome redirect issue(302). Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @Daemon You should add the headers in the redirected url too. What is the POST doing in your case?

Comment: @MDDanish In fact the browser launches the preflight request itself if falls in the criteria, You don't have to trigger it yourselft.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable cross domain request in server with

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```

Comment: I already did that... Now, I am get bit more closer to the root of problem. It says to make OPTIONS request before POST or GET... Any Idea over triggering OPTIONS request .

Comment: Mozilla Console Shows: CORS preflight channel did not succeed