# CORS issue when consuming an express-js webservice that uses res.redirect for sending to a specific route depending on the version needed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web-services

Following some tutorials found on the web, most of them from scotch.io, I started building a REST web service based on express/nodejs and in order to make it more robust i'm managing different versions of the endpoints to maintain access to legacy systems.

On my main .js file in nodejs i'm managing the versioning as follows:

```
// Versioned routes 
// -- Newer versions must be added on the bottom.
var VERSIONS = {
  'Version 1': '/v1'
};

var lastVersion = '';

for (var version in VERSIONS) {
  app.use(VERSIONS[version], require('./versions' + VERSIONS[version]));
  lastVersion = VERSIONS[version];
}
```

So if an application wants to reach an specific version of my endpoints they have to provide the version in the URL https: //myserver.ws/ method/v1/endpoint but if they don't provide the version in the URL I want them to redirect the request to the latest version on the endpoint and I created this catch-all:

```
// Non-versioned endpoints backwards compability
// -- Sends to the latest version available if not specified on the URL endpoint.
app.all('/*', function (req, res) {
  var newRoute = lastVersion + req.path;
  res.redirect(303,newRoute);
});
```

Because I know there are CORS constrains when doing this kind of redirect and I have to allow access for external mobile and web applications I implemented above this code a CORS rule as follows:

```
//CORS middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "platformToken, Authorization, Content-Type,Content-Length, cache-control, X-Requested-With, postman-token");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");
  next();
});
```

Then, if the end user tries to consume my webservice as https:// myserver.ws/ method/ endpoint the res.redirect will change the request and redirect the path to https:// myserver.ws/ method/v1/ endpoint in case the latest version available is v1.

So far during my development I tested using Postman and everything works as expected, but when using this endpoint on a browser I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myserver.ws/validate. 
Redirect from 'http://myserver.ws/validate' to 'http://myserver.ws/v1/validate' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.
```

On the angularjs part i'm consuming the endpoint as follows:

```
var request = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http: //myserver.ws /validate',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
                platformToken: authToken
            },
            data: {
                ssoToken: ssoToken
            }
        }
        $http(request).then(
            function (response) { console.log(response); },
            function (error) { console.log(error);}
        )
```

What i've tried so far is:

- Use my homebrew CORS solution (CORS middleware noted above)
- Use cors() npm module on the webservice Change the Content-Type in order
  not to trigger the preflight
- Test with other tools like Postman
  (actually works on every one, but does not work on the browser).
- Test the endpoints on a different platform (ionic framework app, cordova
  app, win32 app). Nothing works.
- I've tried different redirect codes, nothing works.

I've read about Same-origin policy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy and probably i am doing it wrong so I would like to ask the community for some guidance or if there is a workaround for this I would like to know.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you have a case of a pre-flight is required after a redirect which is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539403/chrome-cancels-cors-xhr-upon-http-302-redirect.  I can't tell whether this is just disallowed entirely by the browser or whether you have to support the `OPTIONS` pre-flight request in your server.

Comment: Hello @jfriend00, I tried that but no luck. I will look for another middleware different than Cors [https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors]