# XHR and 302 redirect in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, redirect, xmlhttprequest

1) We send XHR request with POST method to https://domain1.com/redirect
2) https://domain1.com/redirect returns response with code 302 and redirect to https://domain2.com/?someparams=here

Sometimes (about 60%) browser don't make request to https://domain2.com/?someparams=here . Browser is Chrome or Edge. There is no any problem in Firefox.

If chrome starts by "chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security" all is ok. And if "Disable cache" is activated or service worker is disabled we can reproduce this problem.

There is other similar question on Stackowerflow [Chrome cancels CORS XHR upon HTTP 302 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539403/chrome-cancels-cors-xhr-upon-http-302-redirect) but different is that this problem is not permanent.