# CORS request redirect blocked by browsr

Tags: redirect, cors

Running into an issue with CORS and redirect, here is the simplified flow:

```
Browser ---> K8 NGINX Ingress Controller ---> Service 
                                   |
                                   |
                               Oauth Proxy
```

From Chrome developer tools: Preflight

```
General:
Request URL: https://yyyy
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204
Remote Address: x.x.x.x:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Request headers Preflight

```
:authority: yyyy
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /api
:scheme: https
accept:*/* 
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br 
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9 
access-control-request-headers: x-requested-with
access-control-request-method: GET 
cache-control: no-cache 
origin: https://xxxx 
pragma: no-cache 
referer: https://xxxx 
sec-fetch-dest: empty 
sec-fetch-mode: cors 
sec-fetch-site: same-site 
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers: Preflight

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true 
access-control-allow-headers: DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization 
access-control-allow-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS 
access-control-allow-origin: https://xxx 
access-control-max-age: 1728000 
content-length: 0 
date: Mon, 06 Feb 2023 13:47:36 GMT strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
```

Original Request: Headers

```
:authority: yyyy
:method: GET 
:path: /api 
:scheme: https 
accept: */* 
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br 
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9 
cache-control: no-cache origin: https://xxxx 
pragma: no-cache 
referer: https://xxxx 
sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108" 
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0 
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows" 
sec-fetch-dest: empty 
sec-fetch-mode: cors 
sec-fetch-site: same-site 
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

General

```
Request URL: https://yyy/a/api/a/a?=abc
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302  
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Response Headers:

```
content-length: 138  
content-type: text/html 
date: Mon, 06 Feb 2023 13:47:36 GMT 
location: https://yyyy/oauth2/start?rd=%2Fa%2Fapi%2Fs%2Fb%3Fx%3D1
```

Browser Blocks:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://yyyy from origin 'https://xxxx has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**

**Steps taken so far:**

Read many SO questions for a match including this:

- [Chrome cancels CORS XHR upon HTTP 302 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539403/chrome-cancels-cors-xhr-upon-http-302-redirect)
- The way I understand this article: https://github.com/monmohan/cors-tutorial-practical/tree/master/issue
  is that if the CORS request redirect with 3XX, then the browser should follow  the redirect, but that is not happening
  Read Mozilla docs:
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Tried to follow this three part blog series and its associated github exercise:

- https://software-factotum.medium.com/cross-origin-resource-sharing-a-hands-on-tutorial-fb19748cb3b7

Comment: You make a request to `https://yyyy` and it responds with `location: https://yyyy`? That would be an infinite loop. In your examples, when representing different URLs, please use different example URLs.

Comment: @Quentin -sorry, I updated question to clear that that the redirected URL to include more path details  to show it will be handled by a different ingress controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence when making a preflighted request to a URL that gets a redirect response is:

1. The browser makes a preflight OPTIONS request to A
2. The server must respond with CORS permission
3. The browser makes the real request to A
4. The server must respond with CORS permission **and** the redirect directive to B
5. The browser makes a preflight OPTIONS request to B
6. The server must respond with CORS permission
7. The browser makes the real request to B
8. The server must response with CORS permission **and** the data

---

It isn't entirely clear from your examples, but your sequence appears to be failing at step 4, where you are responding with the redirect directive but **without** CORS permission.